# Check if function call is a variable definition

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if it is possible to check if a function call is returning to a variable definition, or to the global scope.

```
function getName() {
    if (!isVariableDefinition()) {
        console.log("John Doe");
    } else {
        return "John Doe";
}

var name = getName()
// name == "John Doe"

getName()
// Should print "John Doe" to the console
```

I have code that calls for a remote procedure (via AJAX) from a server. At the server, if the procedure is a variable definition, it's name should be saved for other uses, if not, it should just return the results.

```
var result = RPC('getName')
// The server should receive "result" and the call

RPC('getName')
// The server should receive only the call
```

Is that syntax possible?

Comment: My answer remains accurate. `RPC` cannot tell how its return value is used, the syntax is **not** possible. You're trying to use JavaScript in ways it cannot be used. Additionally, if `RPC` uses AJAX to fetch a value, the value will not even be available to return. You will have to either return a promise or pass a callback function into `RPC`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. A function has no idea what is being done with the value it returns.

Comment: Is there any alternative for that?

Comment: @user6907394 No, there isn't. You need to explain what you're trying to do. Without knowing what your *actual* problem is, we can't offer solutions.

Comment: @user6907394 I realize, but my answer remains the same. `RPC` cannot work that way. You need to either use two different functions (a "getter" and a "setter") or pass some additional flag to `RPC` which tells it what to do with the value it fetches.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.